# Google Place Search for Android using a radius

Tags: android, web-services, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm currently getting nearby businesses according to a radius around a given position as well as the type of business using the Google WebApp, as shown here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/

However, I noticed this on Google documentation :

> The Google Places API Web Service is for use in server applications. If you're building a client-side application, take a look at the Google Places API for Android and the Places Library in the Google Maps JavaScript API.

So, I tried to find an equivalent method using only the Android Api, without result. I know my question is a bit borderline, but what should I use in Android? Or is it okay to keep going with the Web Service?

Thank you,

Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sample and Demo u refer as WebService is an Example of Google Places API [Nearby Search Requests]. That one way using the Places API u can search for Places.

Don't get confused Google Places API Web Service is a service that returns information about places and using the APIs u can access the Places data. Well [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) is the link that will help u to understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually integrate Web service with Android. Here is a [code sample](https://github.com/boonhero/android-webservice) that could help you do this.

The concept of Android web service is that you can store the response from the web service request in a json file then you can manipulate the file programmatically then use the data into your android application, but not restricted to it.